# application crashes only when run  on device with warning "Application 'xxxxxxx' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11."

Tags: iphone, crash

My iphone application crashes when run on the device with warning ...

`Application 'xxxxxx' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11.`

However it does not crash in the simulator and also on the device when i have enabled breakpoints and debug mode(in both simultor and when debugging on device i have enabled nszombies and mallocstacklogging nocompact variables).How to debug this issue??

attaching the crash log

```
Date/Time:       2012-02-27 18:04:36.176 +0530
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xf6496811
Crashed Thread:  5

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libicucore.A.dylib              0x355625a8 icu::Locale::getRoot() + 28
1   libicucore.A.dylib              0x3554846c ures_getStringByKeyWithFallback + 36
2   libicucore.A.dylib              0x355f8442 icu::NumberingSystem::createInstance(icu::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) + 110
3   libicucore.A.dylib              0x35548c52 icu::DecimalFormatSymbols::initialize(icu::Locale const&, UErrorCode&, signed char) + 130
4   libicucore.A.dylib              0x355f7452 icu::NumberFormat::makeInstance(icu::Locale const&, UNumberFormatStyle, UErrorCode&) + 162
5   libicucore.A.dylib              0x35548738 unum_open + 504
6   CoreFoundation                  0x33fa3228 0x33f5e000 + 283176
7   Foundation                      0x32f49db0 0x32f1a000 + 196016
8   Myapp                               0x00159bea +[UtilityFunctions convertStringToCurrency:] (UtilityFunctions.m:71)
9   Myapp                               0x00159f08 +[UtilityFunctions convertStringToCurrencyWithZeroFloat:] (UtilityFunctions.m:123)
10  Myapp                               0x000b8f7a -[MainScreenViewController getValueForTextFieldWithName:] (MainScreenViewController.m:768)
11  Myapp                               0x000b78f4 -[MainScreenViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] (MainScreenViewController.m:497)
12  UIKit                           0x371f59c4 0x37192000 + 408004
13  UIKit                           0x371f4aa2 0x37192000 + 404130
14  UIKit                           0x371f422c 0x37192000 + 401964
15  UIKit                           0x37198d44 0x37192000 + 27972
16  CoreFoundation                  0x33f76224 0x33f5e000 + 98852
17  QuartzCore                      0x32c8037a 0x32c7a000 + 25466
18  QuartzCore                      0x32c7ff92 0x32c7a000 + 24466
19  QuartzCore                      0x32c84114 0x32c7a000 + 41236
20  QuartzCore                      0x32c83e50 0x32c7a000 + 40528
21  QuartzCore                      0x32c7bd7e 0x32c7a000 + 7550
22  CoreFoundation                  0x33febb44 0x33f5e000 + 580420
23  CoreFoundation                  0x33fe9d80 0x33f5e000 + 572800
24  CoreFoundation                  0x33fea0da 0x33f5e000 + 573658
25  CoreFoundation                  0x33f6d4d6 0x33f5e000 + 62678
26  CoreFoundation                  0x33f6d39e 0x33f5e000 + 62366
27  GraphicsServices                0x323c2fc6 0x323bf000 + 16326
28  UIKit                           0x371c373c 0x37192000 + 202556
29  Myapp                               0x000b1412 main (main.m:14)
30  Myapp                               0x000b13d0 start + 32

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x376323b4 0x37631000 + 5044
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x36894e78 0x36888000 + 52856
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x36894b96 0x36888000 + 52118

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37642cd4 0x37631000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3651630a 0x3650c000 + 41738
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3651609c 0x3650c000 + 41116

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37642cd4 0x37631000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3651630a 0x3650c000 + 41738
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3651609c 0x3650c000 + 41116

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x376420d8 0x37631000 + 69848
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3650ec44 0x3650c000 + 11332
2   WebCore                         0x3499a36c 0x34994000 + 25452
3   WebCore                         0x3499a670 0x34994000 + 26224
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33febb44 0x33f5e000 + 580420
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33fe9d80 0x33f5e000 + 572800
6   CoreFoundation                  0x33fea19a 0x33f5e000 + 573850
7   CoreFoundation                  0x33f6d4d6 0x33f5e000 + 62678
8   CoreFoundation                  0x33f6d39e 0x33f5e000 + 62366
9   WebCore                         0x34a3c128 0x34994000 + 688424
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3651bc16 0x3650c000 + 64534
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3651bad0 0x3650c000 + 64208

Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32033fbc 0x32030000 + 16316
1   Myapp                               0x00158684 -[SellingCostsVC dealloc] (SellingCostsVC.m:1639)
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x320350be 0x32030000 + 20670
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32036db0 0x32030000 + 28080
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32035e06 0x32030000 + 24070
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32035d22 0x32030000 + 23842
6   CoreFoundation                  0x33f67e88 0x33f5e000 + 40584
7   Foundation                      0x32f1dc58 0x32f1a000 + 15448
8   Myapp                               0x000bb6f8 -[MainScreenViewController calculateValues] (MainScreenViewController.m:1204)
9   Foundation                      0x32f2aa8a 0x32f1a000 + 68234
10  Foundation                      0x32fbe59a 0x32f1a000 + 673178
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3651bc16 0x3650c000 + 64534
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3651bad0 0x3650c000 + 64208

Thread 5 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x000f0000    r1: 0x3846b09c      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0xf6496809    r5: 0x02b04048      r6: 0x02b04048      r7: 0x02b0360c
    r8: 0x0d270028    r9: 0x0e11ac27     r10: 0x0d270028     r11: 0xa3a3a3a3
    ip: 0x3f576454    sp: 0x02b0359c      lr: 0x0015868b      pc: 0x32033fbc
  cpsr: 0x20000030
```

Comment: This is most likely due to code optimalization for non-debug builds. Can you access the crash log on the device? Posting it would help.

Comment: @PeterSarnowski added the crash report

Comment: did you ever find out?? I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: @AlbertoM  if u have the crash log like the one above..its possible ..to get the crash log u need to build it in release mode.. then in the crash log check which thread is crashing...its written at the top... then read the stacktrace for that thread in reverse...the top most line showing some method you wrote will be the cause of crash

Answer (score 1):

The crash log gives you line numbers for about where it went bad; you can use NSLog for "printf debugging" to narrow it down. This blogger explains how to make NSLog useful when running on hardware:
http://objcolumnist.com/2009/12/19/redirecting-nslog-to-a-log-file/

Edit: actually, with the tip I linked you could also do printf debugging with actual printf.